# Is it possible to navigate over mat-tabs (Angular Material) using tabulator instead of arrows?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

Angular mat-tabs provides navigation over tabs using arrows, however I need to implement navigation based on tabulator button on the keyboard. Is It possible at all?
tabindex property seems to not work

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ku56zi?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your link to https://stackblitz.com/ is not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ku56zi-nl2wod?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts

You can bind [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" of matTabGroup to your variable